# Update value of onClick dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding a quantity-field to an orderform where the adding of an item to the card is  done this way:

```
        function updateArchive(id,quant) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "' . GBC_PLUGIN_URL . '/includes/gb-order.php",
        data: { "gbID": id , "qtty": quant },
        success: function(data){
            alert("' . __('Item added successfully!', 'gbcart') . '");
        },
        error: function(data){ 
            alert("' . __('This item already exists!', 'gbcart') . '");
        },
    });
}
```

The quantity is of the Items which are put into the cart are set with "quant", well, here's my problem:

The function "updateArchive" is started with the following command:

```
    <td class="basket"><a href="#" class="gb-button" onclick="updateArchive(125,5); return false;">' . __('Auf die Bestellliste', 'gbcart') . '</a></td>
```

And the only thing i need to dynamicly change is the number "5" in the above example.

When I insert a number in an input, then this number needs to appear instead of the "5".

Comment: Hi, here's the markup for the input.
'<input type="text" id="quant282" value="0">'
You can test the script under the following link:
link](http://siebrandsfisch.de/wp/diverse-artikel-raucherfischgewurze-etc/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function updateArchive(id) {
    var quant = $('input').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "' . GBC_PLUGIN_URL . '/includes/gb-order.php",
        data: { "gbID": id , "qtty": quant },
        success: function(data){
            alert("' . __('Item added successfully!', 'gbcart') . '");
        },
        error: function(data){ 
            alert("' . __('This item already exists!', 'gbcart') . '");
        },
    });
}
```

Change the `$('input')` to the preferred class / id.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid putting javascript in your elements like that. Try using a click listener instead:

HTML:

```
<td class="basket"><a href="#" class="gb-button" data-id="125">' . __('Auf die Bestellliste', 'gbcart') . '</a>
</td>
<input id="myinput" />
```

JS: (the DOM must be loaded before this code, best way to do that is to wrap it within `$(document).ready( function() { [here] });`)

```
$(".gb-button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //to prevent default action of anchor
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var quant = $("#myinput").val();
    alert("id = "+id+", quant = "+quant); // to see it works
/*  jQuery.ajax({
     ... your code here
    });*/
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kx3qL/)